# Can you explain why a dotnet console app works a different way to C console app in back ground mode?

Tags: c#, c, background, console, jobs

I am reading a online book to get better idea of how OS works, following its example code:

[Operating Systems: Three Easy Ways](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/)

In its introduction section,
[Page 3](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/intro.pdf)

I found a C code in cpu.c file like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include "common.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "usage: cpu <string>\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  char *str = argv[1];

  while (1) {
    Spin(1);
    printf("%s\n", str);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The book compiles the file like this:

```
prompt> gcc -o cpu cpu.c -Wall
```

I, as a C# user, converted it into the equivalent C# code (in top level statements) for a dotnet 6 console app:

```
var timer = new PeriodicTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

while (await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync())
{
    if (args.Length == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No Arguments");
        break;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(args[0]);
}
```

This code shows the exactly same result as the book does when executed single.
However, the problem is when executed multiple as back ground jobs.

The book execution:

```
prompt> ./cpu A & ./cpu B & ./cpu C & ./cpu D &
```

and its result:

```
[1] 7353
[2] 7354
[3] 7355
[4] 7356
A
B
D
C
A
B
D
C
A
...
```

I did the same shell command in Windows Powershell 7 in my windows computer:

```
prompt> .\CPU.exe A & .\CPU.exe B &
```

but the result is like this only;

```
Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location    Command
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------    -------
1      Job1            BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost   Shell.Man…
3      Job3            BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost   Shell.Man…
```

PowerShell wouldn't print any characters from background jobs at all.

Can anybody explain why I got the result and, if possible, how I can fix it so that I can get the same result with the book?

Comment: When working with job, you need to use `Receive-Job` to read the content that was printed by the job up to this point.

Comment: @SagePourpre Can you show a shell script to be used it in this case?

Comment: PowerShell is nothing like a posix shell. CMD.exe would probably be closer.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I tried with CMD, window terminal and powershell. With cmd, jobs starts one after one when the former job is cancelled by ^C. they didn't work concurrently.

Comment: Yeah, now that I'm looking for it, I don't see how CMD / .bat script could launch background jobs without creating separate windows. The way stdout is merged with multiple processes on windows should appear to have the same behaviour as posix C. Though you might have to run a bash shell if you really want to see the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a surface level, the Powershell [& operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#background-operator-) appears to be similar to the posix shell [& operator](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_03_02). Designed with the same goals.

When a posix shell process uses `fork()` and `exec()` to spawn a child process, all open file handles will be shared. Unless you explicitly specify how to redirect or pipe their output.

Powershell [Jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job?view=powershell-7.2) have their standard output redirected to a new pipe, so you can decide when to read each job's output.

The windows OS is capable of the same behaviour as posix C. However the CMD.exe `&` operator is a sequential operation. Equivalent to the posix `;`. I can't find a reference to an operation with the same background job behaviour.

You could install a bash shell if you wish to repeat the same example on each OS.

Or you could emulate how the shell behaves by changing your C# console program to `Process.Start()` itself as a child process when you pass in multiple arguments.

Comment: Thanks, Jeremy. Windows has Bash built in and configured to use it by setting Linux function. However, Bash starts but ends immediately. so, I can' test it.

Comment: I think that bash.exe is a gateway to the windows subsystem for linux. In other words, you're using linux bash on a linux kernel.